Log file: Selection of specific log content inside log file by start and end date
I am working on log analysis where I need to analyze a log file by first extracting the dates within the file. Then, I need to use these dates to define a start date and an end date. Based on the selected start and end dates, only the specific content within that range should be available, effectively filtering the log content by date.
I have managed to successfully extract the dates using a regex format, but the function to filter the log content based on the start and end dates is not working as expected.
@staticmethod
    def filter_log_entries(log_content, start_date, end_date):
        start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d/%b/%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        end_datetime = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d/%b/%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

        # Adjust end_datetime to include the entire end day
        end_datetime = end_datetime + timedelta(days=1) - timedelta(seconds=1)

        log_entry_pattern = re.compile(r'\[(\d{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [+-]\d{4})\]')
        filtered_entries = []

        for line in log_content.split('\n'):
            match = log_entry_pattern.search(line)
            if match:
                entry_datetime_str = match.group(1)
                try:
                    entry_datetime = datetime.strptime(entry_datetime_str, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
                    if start_datetime <= entry_datetime <= end_datetime:
                        filtered_entries.append(line)
                except ValueError:
                    st.write(f"Date parsing error for line: {line}")

        filtered_log_content = "\n".join(filtered_entries)

        return filtered_log_content

Log Content (to show):
The date format in the log file is [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000], and the log file ends on [20/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000]. I want to filter the log content so that if I select the date range from 17/May/2015 to 18/May/2015, only the content within this timeline is selected.
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/kibana-search.png HTTP/1.1" 200 203023 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:43 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/kibana-dashboard3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 171717 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:47 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/plugin/highlight/highlight.js HTTP/1.1" 200 26185 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:12 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7697 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:07 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/plugin/notes/notes.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2892 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:34 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/sad-medic.png HTTP/1.1" 200 430406 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:57 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/css/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 38720 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:50 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/css/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 41820 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:24 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/frontend-response-codes.png HTTP/1.1" 200 52878 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:50 +0000] 

Complete Link: https://github.com/linuxacademy/content-elastic-log-samples/blob/master/access.log

What does this have to do with prolog?

It's my mistake, if you can recommend me some tags it would be helpful for me as I didn't find answer and also keywords

Did the answer worked @KhawarIslam

To get content with entry date and exclude the end date you can use below code and in try condition used this rith_st_dt <= ri_entry_dt < rith_ed_dt:
import re
from datetime import datetime, timezone

@staticmethod
def test_rith_filter(rith_lg_cnt_test, ri_strt_dt, ri_ed_dt):
    rith_st_dt = datetime.strptime(ri_strt_dt, '%d/%b/%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    rith_ed_dt = datetime.strptime(ri_ed_dt, '%d/%b/%Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    ri_lg_pt = re.compile(r'\[(\d{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [+-]\d{4})\]')
    Tested_Result_Out = []
    for ri in rith_lg_cnt_test.split('\n'):
        cat = ri_lg_pt.search(ri)
        if cat:
            ri_entry_dt_str = cat.group(1)
            try:
                ri_entry_dt = datetime.strptime(ri_entry_dt_str, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
                if rith_st_dt <= ri_entry_dt < rith_ed_dt:
                    Tested_Result_Out.append(ri)
            except ValueError:
                print(f"There is an error in Parsing it Rithwik Bojja: {ri}")
    ri_res = "\n".join(Tested_Result_Out)
    return ri_res
rith_lg_cnt_test = """
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] "Test .1700.66 Safari/500.99"
83.149.9.216 - - [18/May/2015:12:05:03 +0000] " Rithwik afari/500.99"
83.149.9.216 - - [19/May/2015:14:05:03 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama Bojja .66 Safari/500.99"
"""

ri_strt_dt = "17/May/2015"
ri_ed_dt = "18/May/2015"

test_rith_call = test_rith_filter(rith_lg_cnt_test, ri_strt_dt, ri_ed_dt)
print(test_rith_call)

Output:

